# Exclude a character in regex?

Tags: java, regex

i've been trying to exclude a character in this RegEx, and i can't figure out how.

If i have this RegEx: `.*(horario|horarios|hora).*`

And i want to exclude the letter "a" before the "hora" match, how would this be done? I tried doing
I have tried
     *

```
*.(horario|horarios|((?!a)hora).*
*.(horario|horarios|[^a]hora).*
```

but it didn't work.

Thanks in advance for your answer!

I just want to exclude that single character, only for that word.

Comment: could you provide an example with expected output?

Comment: Is there a chance you really want a [`\b` word boundary](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html)?

Comment: It does match horarios, and now works perfectly, im making a automatic-chat (in spanish), and when someone says in a whole sentence the word "horarios, hora or horario", it matches it and sends an answer saying the customer support time. Been working for a while, but today a user said "Ahora" (Which means now) and it answered with the customer support time. Had to fix that c:

Comment: It will never match `horarios` within the capture group. In that respect it doesn't make sense, its useless.

Comment: If you need a proof...
http://puu.sh/coWrD/5f3aad1a90.png

Comment: @sln is right.  If you look closely at the image you posted, you'll see that it's matching `horario`, not `horarios`.  The regex engine tries the alternatives in the order they're listed, so if one of the alternatives is a prefix of another, you have to list the longer one first.

Comment: Oh sorry, you are right, so basically horarios is there for nothing, since it woudl still match with horario. Sorry and thanks! i'll be deleting it from the code. Im kind of a noob in doing RegExps

Comment: @Sam Thanks, i ended up using a word boundary

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use negative lookbehind

```
(?<!a)hora
```

the regex can be

```
.*(?<!a)(horario|horarios|hora).*
```

`(?<!a)` successful when match is not found

`(horario|horarios|hora).*` matches any pattern, combined ensures `a` cannot precede `hora`

http://regex101.com/r/aK8qI0/1

Comment: Thanks for teaching! Really helpful, would vote up, but i don't have rep :c